# getting dict key using dict value in python

Tags: python, dictionary, key

My question is: How can I get a dictionary key using a dictionary value?

```
d={'dict2': {1: 'one', 2: 'two'}, 'dict1': {3: 'three', 4: 'four'}}
```

I want to get `dict2` the key of the key of `two`.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a recursive solution that can handle arbitrarily nested dictionaries:

```
>>> import collections
>>> def dict_find_recursive(d, target):
...     if not isinstance(d, collections.Mapping):
...         return d == target
...     else:
...         for k in d:
...             if dict_find_recursive(d[k], target) != False:
...                 return k
...     return False
```

It's not as efficient in the long run as a "reverse dictionary," but if you aren't doing such reverse searches frequently, it probably doesn't matter. (Note that you have to explicitly compare the result of `dict_find_recursive(d[k], target)` to `False` because otherwise falsy keys like `''` cause the search to fail. In fact, even this version fails if `False` is used as a key; a fully general solution would use a unique sentinel `object()` to indicate falseness.)

A few usage examples:

```
>>> d = {'dict1': {3: 'three', 4: 'four'}, 'dict2': {1: 'one', 2: 'two'}}
>>> dict_find_recursive(d, 'two')
'dict2'
>>> dict_find_recursive(d, 'five')
False
>>> d = {'dict1': {3: 'three', 4: 'four'}, 'dict2': {1: 'one', 2: 'two'}, 
         'dict3': {1: {1:'five'}, 2: 'six'}}
>>> dict_find_recursive(d, 'five')
'dict3'
>>> dict_find_recursive(d, 'six')
'dict3'
```

If you want to reverse an arbitrarily nested set of dictionaries, recursive generators are your friend:

```
>>> def dict_flatten(d):
...     if not isinstance(d, collections.Mapping):
...         yield d
...     else:
...         for value in d:
...             for item in dict_flatten(d[value]):
...                 yield item
... 
>>> list(dict_flatten(d))
['three', 'four', 'five', 'six', 'one', 'two']
```

The above simply lists all the values in the dictionary that aren't mappings. You can then map each of those values to a key like so:

```
>>> def reverse_nested_dict(d):
...     for k in d:
...         if not isinstance(d[k], collections.Mapping):
...             yield (d[k], k)
...         else:
...             for item in dict_flatten(d[k]):
...                 yield (item, k)
...
```

This generates a iterable of tuples, so no information is lost:

```
>>> for tup in reverse_nested_dict(d):
...     print tup
... 
('three', 'dict1')
('four', 'dict1')
('five', 'dict3')
('six', 'dict3')
('one', 'dict2')
('two', 'dict2')
```

If you know that all your non-mapping values are hashable -- and if you know they are unique, or if you don't care about collisions -- then just pass the resulting tuples to `dict()`:

```
>>> dict(reverse_nested_dict(d))
{'six': 'dict3', 'three': 'dict1', 'two': 'dict2', 'four': 'dict1', 
 'five': 'dict3', 'one': 'dict2'}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to reverse the dictionary, here's another possible solution:

```
def get_key_from_value(my_dict, v):
    for key,value in my_dict.items():
        if value == v:
            return key
    return None

>>> d = {1: 'one', 2: 'two'}
>>> get_key_from_value(d,'two')
2
```

Comment: Same problem as Codemonk's response - it doesn't answer the question. The OP specified d to be a dictionary whose values are dictionaries, not strings.

Answer (score 1):

The following will create a reverse dictionary for the two-level example:

```
d={'dict2': {1: 'one', 2: 'two'}, 'dict1': {3: 'three', 4: 'four'}}
r = {}
for d1 in d:
    for d2 in d[d1]:
        r[d[d1][d2]] = d1
```

The result:

```
>>> r
{'four': 'dict1', 'three': 'dict1', 'two': 'dict2', 'one': 'dict2'}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about the best solution, but one possibility is reversing the dictionary (so that values becomes keys) and then just doing a normal key lookup.  This will reverse a dictionary:

```
forward_dict = { 'key1': 'val1', 'key2': 'val2'}
reverse_dict = dict([(v,k) for k,v in forward_dict.items()])
```

So given "val1", I can just do:

```
reverse_dict["val1"]
```

to find the corresponding key.  There are obvious problems with this solution -- for example, if your values aren't unique, you're going to lose some information.

Comment: This doesn't work if the dictionary contains unhashable values, so it won't work for the example in the question.

Comment: To expand on Peter's explanation, a dictionary is not immutable and thus is not hashable, so a dictionary cannot be the key of a dictionary.  "An object is hashable if it has a hash value which never changes during its lifetime" -- Python glossary.

Answer (score 0):

Write code to reverse the dictionary (i.e. create a new dictionary that maps the values of the old one to the keys of the old one).
Since you seem to be dealing with nested dictionaries, this will obviously be trickier. Figure out the least you need to get your problem solved and code that up (i.e. don't create a solution that will work arbitrary depths of nesting if your problem only deals with dicts in dicts which in turn don't have any dicts)

Answer (score 0):

To handle the nested dictionaries I would do just as [senderle's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8252843/157744) states.

However if in the future it does not contain nested dictionaries, be very careful doing a simple reversal.  By design the dictionary **keys** are unique, but the values do not have this requirement.

If you have values that are the same for multiple keys, when reversing the dictionary you will lose **all but one** of them.  And because dictionaries are not sorted, you could lose different data arbitrarily.

**Example of reversal working:**

```
>>> d={'dict1': 1, 'dict2': 2, 'dict3': 3, 'dict4': 4}
>>> rd = dict([(v,k) for k,v in d.items()])
>>> print d
{'dict4': 4, 'dict1': 1, 'dict3': 3, 'dict2': 2}

>>> print rd
{1: 'dict1', 2: 'dict2', 3: 'dict3', 4: 'dict4'}
```

**Example of reversal failure: Note that `dict4` is lost**

```
>>> d={'dict1': 1, 'dict2': 4, 'dict3': 3, 'dict4': 4}
>>> rd = dict([(v,k) for k,v in d.items()])
>>> print d
{'dict4': 4, 'dict1': 1, 'dict3': 3, 'dict2': 4}

>>> print rd
{1: 'dict1', 3: 'dict3', 4: 'dict2'}
```

Answer (score 0):

here's an example nobody thinks about: (could be used similarly)

```
raw_dict = { 'key1': 'val1', 'key2': 'val2', 'key3': 'val1' }

new_dict = {}
for k,v in raw_dict.items():
    try: new_dict[v].append(k)
    except: new_dict[v] = [k]
```

result:

```
>>> new_dict
{'val2': ['key2'], 'val1': ['key3', 'key1']}
```

maybe not the best of methods, but it works for what I need it for.