# Printing a dictionary with print

Tags: python, python-3.x

Why does

```
 d = {"A":10,"B":20}
 print(*d, sep=" ")
```

Output `A B` and not `10 20`?

And how do i get `10 20`?

Comment: That prints the keys not the dict values

Comment: Note that `*` is **positional** unpacking. When you iterate over a dictionary you get the keys, not the values, hence the result. Use `*d.values()` instead.  BTW: the order of the output is not defined, so don't be surprised if the values end up in a differnt order than what you thought.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [getting dict key using dict value in python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8251876/getting-dict-key-using-dict-value-in-python)

Comment: @NelsCarlson Sorry? Why would this question be a duplicate to a question about nested dictionaries?

Comment: `print(*d.values(), sep=" ")`

Answer (score 3):

Assuming what you want is to print the keys *together* with the values you could use a generator expression:

```
print(' '.join('{}={}'.format(k,v) for k,v in d.items()))
```

or if you prefer to keep the `sep` argument instead of using `str.join`:

```
print(*('{}={}'.format(k,v) for k,v in d.items()),sep=' ')
```

both with output:

```
A=10 B=20
```

Comment: The question says "How do I get `10 20`?" He doesn't seem to want the keys.

Comment: @Barmar I agree, yet, the title is quite open (*printing a dictionary*), and might result in other users stumbling on this page in search of a way to print both keys and values.

Answer (score 2):

simply write

```
print (*d.values() )
```

Answer (score 1):

Please see a demo for print introduction:

```
>>> def demo(p, *args, **kwargs):
...     print(args)
...     print(kwargs)
...
>>> demo(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, callback='demo_callback')
(1, 2, 3, 4)
{'callback': 'demo_callback'}
```

1. The `*` syntax requires a tuple/list;
2. The `**` syntax requires a dictionary; each key-value pair in the dictionary becomes a keyword argument.

> print(*objects, sep=' ', end='\n', file=sys.stdout, flush=False)
>
> Print objects to the text stream file, separated by sep and followed by end. sep, end and file, if present, must be given as keyword arguments.
>
> All non-keyword arguments are converted to strings like str() does and written to the stream, separated by sep and followed by end. Both sep and end must be strings; they can also be None, which means to use the default values. If no objects are given, print() will just write end.
>
> The file argument must be an object with a write(string) method; if it is not present or None, sys.stdout will be used. Since printed arguments are converted to text strings, print() cannot be used with binary mode file objects. For these, use file.write(...) instead.
>
> Whether output is buffered is usually determined by file, but if the flush keyword argument is true, the stream is forcibly flushed.

```
>>> print(d, sep=" ")
{'B': 20, 'A': 10}
>>> print(*d, sep=" ")
B A
>>> print(**d, sep=" ")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'B' is an invalid keyword argument for this function
```

---

This is a valid way:

```
>>> print(*d.values(), sep=" ")
```